# How can I detect STDOUT redirection in PHP CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I've a PHP CLI script that uses shell escape sequences for bolding, but I want to be able to disable these automatically when the script's being redirected (eg to a log file).

I can find ways to detect STDOUT redirection in everything but PHP so far... so can anyone tell me how it *is* done in PHP?

Comment: @bcsanches Yup - lost track of which site was which. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
if(posix_isatty(STDOUT))
    echo "No Redirection";
else
    echo "Redirection!";
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was trying to find out. Works too (but you knew that).

To try and ensure it wouldn't bail in windows or non-posix systems, I've also called is_function('posix_isatty') before trying the test.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can use this:

```
$b = stream_isatty(STDIN);
if ($b) {
   echo "no redirect\n";
} else {
   echo "redirect\n";
}
```

https://php.net/function.stream-isatty