# How can I debug redirecting requests in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, redirect, phpstorm

I have an webapp for CAD stuff and want to add a single sign on. If the user has no set session token I redirect him to an other website to get token if he is allowed to.

I have both source codes, both are written in PHP. I want to debug even the redirect if possible.

My redirect looks like this:

```
header("Location: localhost/SSO/index.php?reURL=localhost/PLM/index.php");
```

I have a working PhpStorm setup for debugging with the internal PHP cli.I can debug my sites, but after sending the header the debugging just stops. Is there a way to debug redirects?

My site and the validation are in different Projects/folders. I tried to put both in the same folder but it did not change the behavior.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the script that you are redirecting too

Comment: do you redirect to the same local domain, I mean if always localhost or something else ?
do you place breakpoints on the page you are redirecting too ?
if you got more than 1 domains (pointing to 127.0.0.1) you should enable your debug on both

Comment: @pavelbere: for now I have both on localhost for testing localhost/PLM/index.php is my application, localhost/SSO/index.php is the token thingy.
Yes I have set breakpoints in both of them. I can debug each of the two projects individualy and the breakpoints are hit.

Comment: Try enabling XDebug logs & checking them: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs

Comment: If that's your actual code (i.e., you forgot the protocol prefix in the URL) the browser will redirect to `http://localhost/localhost/SSO/index.php`. Unless you have a 404 Not Found Handler implemented in PHP, that's where it all ends from PHP perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (posix_isatty(STDOUT)) {
  echo "No Redirection";
} else {
  echo "Redirection!";
}
```

Solution provided to a similar question years back. You may visit the link below for more details

[How can I detect STDOUT redirection in PHP CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730268/how-can-i-detect-stdout-redirection-in-php-cli)

Comment: Please don't duplicate content. If this was the answer, then the best path would be to close the question as duplicate of that other question. But I think you've misread the issue in the first place. Apart from the term "redirection", they don't have anything in common. This question is about HTTP (`Location` header and 302 status code) and yours talks about shell pipes.